# PHP script doesnt execute after set_time_limit(0)

Tags: php, macos, apache, server, php-5.6

I've got set_time_limit(0) added on one of my PHP scripts where I want the script to call an API to fetch details, which is slow.

But the PHP script wont execute after the set_time_limit(0) on my PHP installation.

To give some more information.

**If I have this script**

```
<?php

echo "Hello I am here<br>";

set_time_limit(1);

echo "Hello I am still here<br>";
```

**It Returns**

```
Hello I am here
Hello I am still here
```

**If I have this**

```
<?php

echo "Hello I am here<br>";

set_time_limit(0);

echo "Hello I am still here<br>";
```

It doesn't return anything but the browser keeps spinning.

I've got OSX sierra, and PHP 5.6 any help to debug would this will be great.

Comment: You need to post more information.  How long does the API call take?

Comment: Any script that relies on an infinite timeout is broken. If you need a long running script write it as a shell script and execute it using something like cron or something similar. In your instance I would consider performing the API call and caching the details locally which your website is able to use instead.

The HTTP server has limited resources, if a lot of people trigger that long request at once, it will effectively DoS your server.

Comment: What do you mean exactly `wont execute`? Fails with error, just dies, never ends?

Comment: @Axalix it never ends.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, but not sure why this was happening.

I had PHP installed via brew, and a bundled version from http://php-osx.liip.ch/ was installed.

That was creating issues with the set_time_limit function. However when I switch back, and make php using the binaries the issue seem to be gone.

Still not sure whats happening in the first please.